# Load Keystore key to memory on app startup or retrieve it from Keystore on every encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: android, security

In my app - I have encrypted preferences and I use an Android Keystore key to encrypt and decrypt them.

On some, older devices (Android 5.x) I see a lot of these logcat messages :

> 03-10 14:35:37.601 2573-2573/? W/keystore: Could not read
>   CACERT_KEY_ALIAS

During a certain operation - the app might decrypt 15-20 values in a very short amount of time and I assume the this load on the Keystore might be the cause.

One solution that can be to retrieve the key during app startup and hold a reference to it throughout a whole operation or even throughout the execution of the app.

FYI - I use the SecretKey object which doesn't expose the actual key (I cannot get the key when debugging as the SecretKey.getEncoded() method returns null). When encrypting/decrypting I pass the SecretKey object to the cipher object of the security provider (and the key is somehow passed under the hood).

Does that have any security implications? can someone retrieve a key by examining the app's memory heap or a dump? any thoughts? recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: "can someone retrieve a key by examining the app's memory heap or a dump?" -- if you are holding it in memory, yes.

Comment: Well, the answer is not so straight forward. When I use the Keystore key , as a developer debugging the app, the SecretKey object I have reference to - does provide access to the actual byte array holding the key. I pass the SecretKey object to the cypher object for encrypting/decrypting. I don't know how the key is passed/used under the hood but it's not clear of it's stored in the app's memory space or handled separately by the security provider.

Comment: Sorry, that particular pattern was not obvious from your question. I assumed that you had already used the `SecretKey` and were holding onto the decrypted value, which happens to be the key to something else (e.g., whatever you are using for encrypted preferences). You might consider a [mcve] to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: I'll edit the question to reflect the usage of the SecretKey, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update : after searching extensively for an answer about weather a mey held in memory can be retrieved from a mem dump of any other process snapshot and failing to find one - we decided not to keep the keystore key into memory. It will have to be retrieved every time we decrypt a value.

Comment: Isn't it expensive (in terms of performance)?

Comment: yes but it's more important to keep the secret key secure. if it's in memory - someone can retrieve a memory dump of your app and extract the secret key.